# Visual Studio crash on F5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012 to develop SharePoint 2010 application.

I recently have installed Visual Studio 2013 RC, but I don't use it.

I still use VS 2012, but I can't start with debug (F5) anymore. Visual Studio crashes.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to start debugging on the web server. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor has been closed on the remote machine.

Click Help for more information.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

In the event log I get this message :

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.60610.1, time stamp: 0x51b52140
Faulting module name: vsdebug.dll, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f149a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00007329
Faulting process id: 0xfe8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceb51ac1e92518
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\vsdebug.dll
Report Id: 202357b5-210f-11e3-80bd-00155d67020d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I don't know if its related, but the faulting module points to the **10.0** folder instead of the **11.0**.

I repaired VS 2012, with no more success.

Any suggestion?

**[edit]** I removed my answer, as the problem reappeared

Comment: VS2010 is v10, VS2012 is v11 and VS2013 is v12. It looks like you also have VS2010, isn't it?

Comment: Not directly. I have Sql server 2012 management tools, which are based on the VS 2010 engine.

Comment: @SteveB Can you try to Set platform target to x86 in Properties -> Build?

Comment: @plurby: no. SharePoint 2010 is 64 bits only.

Comment: @SteveB Sorry it worked for me several times but not with Sharepoint. Another idea is to try cleaning your Symbol Cache then restart VS?

Comment: @plurby: thanks for trying to help me, but as I said in my answer, I restored an older backup of my computer, before the problem occurs. I'm no more able to test your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Because I believe my question is too specific to my setup, I simply revert back to a previous state of my dev computer.

It works again.